# Determining "Borrow" when subtracting binary numbers

Tags: c#, binary-data

I am trying to write a chip8 emulator in C#. It will be necessary to simulate in software the operations that take place in hardware on the real chip.

There is an opcode that requires detecting a whether a borrow occurred during the subtraction of two binary numbers.

```
Byte1 - Byte2
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can use C# to tell if a borrow occurred or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to compare each bit of the bytes...  If the second byte bit is set but not the first, you have a borrow condition:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    byte b1 = byte.Parse(args[0]);
    byte b2 = byte.Parse(args[1]);

    bool borrow = false;
    for (int mask = 0x01; mask <= 0x80; mask <<= 1) {
        if ((b2 & mask) > (b1 & mask)) {
            borrow = true;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b1, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b2, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    Console.WriteLine("borrowed: {0}", borrow);
}
```

There may be a very clever boolean logic that gives you the answer, but I cannot come up with it now.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is what I was trying to do when I posted this, I am going to try this today!

Answer (score 4):

After searching in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP-8) for the mysterious opcode you didn't mention, and looking for some implementations. I can conclude that the opcodes 8XY5 and 8XY7 (where X and Y are register identifiers) will do substractions.

For 8XY5 the register X will be set to the value of the register X minus the value of the register Y. And the register F will be set to 1 if the value of the register Y is greater or equal to the value of the register X (0 otherwise).

For 8XY7 the register X will be set to the value of the register Y minus the value of the register X. And the register F will be set to 1 if the value of the register X is greater or equal to the value of the register Y (0 otherwise).

This is the "pseudo"-code for 8XY5:

```
x = opcode[1]
y = opcode[2]
if (register[x] >= register[y])
    register[0xF] = 1
else
    register[0xF] = 0
result = register[x] - register[y]
if result < 0
    result += 256
register[x] = result
```

and this is the "pseudo"-code for 8XY7:

```
x = opcode[1]
y = opcode[2]
if (register[y] >= register[x])
    register[0xF] = 1
else
    register[0xF] = 0
result = register[y] - register[x]
if result < 0
    result += 256
register[x] = result
```

And here is a C# implementation:

```
const byte B_0 = 0x0;
const byte B_1 = 0x1;
const byte B_F = 0xF;

static void Main()
{
    byte[] registers = new byte[16];
    registers[0x1] = 255;
    registers[0x2] = 127;
    Opcode8XY5(registers, 1, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(registers[0x1]);
    Console.WriteLine(registers[0x2]);
    Console.WriteLine(registers[0xF]);
    Opcode8XY7(registers, 1, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(registers[0x1]);
    Console.WriteLine(registers[0x2]);
    Console.WriteLine(registers[0xF]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Opcode8XY5(byte[] registers, byte x, byte y)
{
    registers[B_F] = registers[x] >= registers[y] ? B_1 : B_0;
    registers[x] = (byte)(registers[x] - registers[y]);
}

static void Opcode8XY7(byte[] registers, byte x, byte y)
{
    registers[B_F] = registers[y] >= registers[x] ? B_1 : B_0;
    registers[x] = (byte)(registers[y] - registers[x]);
}
```

Check [this](http://www.zophar.net/chip8/chuit.html) implementation for reference.

Comment: This is great, but the only issue I see is that it dosen't do a bit by bit comparison.

Comment: @MrAlt Six things: 1) in base 256 5 - 3 is not a borrow 2) In decimal 5 - 3 is not a borrow, 3) In binary 5 - 3 (101 - 11) is a borrow, 4) With jheddings' code 5 - 3 is a borrow, 5) with my code 5 - 3 is not a borrow, 6) my code is besed on existing emulators. You are free to make your own conclution. Independly of how you implement it, Make sure you test it thoroughly.

Comment: @Theraot 10 things: 0) you should have started counting from 0 :p 1) what's 'base 256'?

Comment: @vexe 1) I think of these as ordinals not indexes, 2) it means that you need to carry at 256. That is, that 256 is one unit of the second order (aka "10" = 256 in such base) even tho there is NO intention to represent numbers in base 256, it is just for computation. Chip8 uses base 256, because the size of its registers is 8 (and 2^8 = 256) hence the name. Bubo asked for Chip8 borrow but apparently wanted binary borrow instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the math with wider type provided that the typecast was not sign-propagating. Then check if the result has the 8th bit set to 1. If it is set then borrowing had place. Then save a result as byte.